# How to do a 3D line plot in gnuplot using x, y, z data contained in a text file?

Tags: gnuplot, line-plot

I have a text file (named `lorenz-phase.txt`, as you can probably guess it is the solution to the Lorenz equations) that contains data of the format:

```
1 1 1
1.01257 1.25992 0.984891
1.04882 1.524 0.973114
1.10721 1.79831 0.965159
1.18687 2.08854 0.961737
```

and so forth, where the first column is my x values, the second column is my y values and the third column is my z values. I would like to plot a 3D line plot of this data using gnuplot. Is this possible and how is it done? Google has not given me an answer on this front, as the plots I could find were when a parametric function describes the plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `splot` command for 3d plots, and `with lines` for lines:

```
splot "lorenz-phase.txt" using 1:2:3 with lines
```

My first google result with keywords `gnuplot 3d line` is [this one](http://lowrank.net/gnuplot/plot3d2-e.html).

Comment: How do I export the plot as an svg? I know how to with 2D plots as I have code for that, it is [here](https://github.com/fusion809/CPP-Math-Projects/blob/master/Lorenz-Equations/lorenz.gp).

Comment: Gnuplot uses the command `plot` for 2D plots and `splot` for 3D plots.  The code for generating svg output is the same.